gcloud list dataflow job cost
Hello this may dumb question but I am not yet found the answer anywhere, currently I have some needs to execute command to list dataflow job like below
gcloud dataflow jobs list --status=done --limit=5

which is I am about to execute this frequent using shell scripting to list if any failed/running job in last 5 jobs, my question is does google will charge me a lot if I execute this command suppose like every 30mins once.

Not a programming question and so ill-suited to Stack overflow. Generally (not always!) control plane APIs (CRUD resources) are free. You should review the Cloud Dataflow pricing for a definitive answer but it appears that projects.jobs.list APIs are free.

I'm unfamiliar with Dataflow but, rather than poll the service for failed jobs, you may be better placed using Cloud Monitoring (Alerts) to be notified on state.
